# Javascript replace string with list from array

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is a normal sentence. I need to replace the characters in the string if they are found in a given array. For example,

```
const arr = ["(model: Audi)", "(model: Kia)"];
```

if the string is:

```
"How is your (model: Audi) today?";
```

The result should be `"How is your Audi today?"`.

Is there a way to do this with regex? I read somewhere that regex has better performance. I've tried looping thru the array then replacing the characters but I couldnt get it working and my solution would have nested loops due to the given string

Comment: Show us what you have tried to do so far.

Comment: If they all match that pattern, do you need the array at all? `"How is your (model: Audi) today?".replace(/\([^:]+:\s([^\)]+)\)/, '$1')`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = ["(model: Audi)", "(model: Kia)"];
let string = "How is your (model: Audi) today?";
for (let data of arr){
  string = string.replace(data, data.split(": ")[1].replace(")",""))
}
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is the simplest I have managed to do.

However, I myself kind of consider it a bad solution.

Let me know if it helps at all...

```js
const myString = "How is your (model: Audi) today?";
const arr = ["(model: Audi)", "(model: Kia)"];

arr.forEach(item => {
  const part = item.match(/\w+\)$/)[0];
  const subPart = part.substring(0, part.length - 1);

  if (myString.includes(item))
    console.log(myString.replace(item, subPart));
});
```